# Directory to save reference files for Pandoc on OS X?

Tags: type-conversion, osx-mountain-lion, macvim, implicit-conversion, pandoc

I've been toying with this all day.

From my understanding, you can use reference files with desired fonts, headers, etc.
when doing file conversions with Pandoc.

For example: 
If I wanted to convert the markdown file 'filename.md' to a .docx file of the same name
using a reference file I'd enter into the command line:

```
pandoc --reference-docx=reference.docx filename.md -o filename.docx
```

The problem I'm having is when I run through this command, it returns:

```
pandoc: reference.docx: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

After reading online about where to keep my reference docs, a few sites mentioned saving under '.pandoc/', which didn't exist.  My first guess was that because I used the OS X installer that it didn't create it.  So I made one, and saved a reference.docx to that directory.

I restarted and tried the command again a few different ways, no dice.  My guess is that I was still saving my reference files to the wrong directory, haven't sourced something correctly, or I'm missing some point completely.

**UPDATE**

I went with the obvious and tried the commands from within the same directory I had my reference files in.  Tabbing through, syntax is good, directory is good, all files in the right place, but now I have a new error:

```
pandoc: Did not find end of central directory signature. Failed reading at byte position 4
```

This is apparently a zip file issue now...

If anyone knows a quick fix that'd be helpful, otherwise I'm reinstalling a different version I've found of Pandoc with some extra resources, hopefully that'll solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling from source and using a different reference doc solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

1.set --data-dir=your PATH,pandoc automatic look for reference.docx in dara-dir.
  but must disable --reference-doc.

2.set --reference-doc=your.docx,and put your.docx same dir with your.md,but must disable --data-dir.

1 or 2 is ok when pandoc convert markdown to docx.